# Looking for daf yomi app recommendations

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, phone, daf-yomi

Are there any good daf yomi apps? I saw the video for the artscroll app but it doesn't seem to be out yet. Any recommendations?

Comment: The Artscroll app is available here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/artscroll-digital-library/id536661409?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Someone please tell Artscroll that there are a few of us with Android devices.

Comment: @SethJ I read an article that suggested that they planned to roll out the app to iPhone and Android in the near future.

Comment: I heard the new Koren English Talmud is/did come out with an app starting this cycle.

Comment: The siyum's program guide "HaSiyum" had an ad for every different system with an analysis (on their own terms, though) of it.

Comment: kollel iyun hadaf has its stuff in epub format. see dafyomi.see http://dafyomi.co.il/members/login.php

Answer (score 4):

OU have recently produced a new website/app called [Alldaf.org](https://alldaf.org/).

Features (you can [customize your feed](https://alldaf.org/preferences) according to your interests from the following features):

- Daf Hayomi Shiurim from a selection of famous Maggidei Shiur
- Point by Point elucidation of every Tosfos in English
- [Supplementary bite-sized audio miniseries](https://alldaf.org/series/):

  - Daf in Practice
  - Daf in Halacha
  - Daf in Jewish History
  - Daf in Depth (Iyun Hadaf)
  - Daf intro
  - Pesukei Hadaf
- Resource material for further learning

  - Mareh Mekomos in Halacha
  - Mareh Mekomos in Lomdus
  - Advanced Shiurim of Rishonim & Achronim on the Daf

Answer (score 3):

There is a new free daf yomi app called "portal hadaf hyomi"

The App includes many great features:

1. The entire Talmud in clear fonts
2. Talmud lessons to listen to and download, in Hebrew, English and Yiddish
3. Articles, Leaflets,books and other helpful tools
4. A location map for venues in which you can attend "Daf Hayomi" lectures
5. A Calendar with enables the user to keep track of hies learning

download link

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pwrtl-hdp-hywmy/id534520510?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: binyamin, thanks for your detailed answer, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1772/binyamin), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

An app which can be used on Android is one named 'Real Clear Daf' and as described the Daf is explained real clear.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. If I could, I would give an additional vote because I just LOVE your ID name, esp. for an answer about learning.

Comment: Or ‘explained clearly’

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Crowded Road's iTalmud](http://crowdedroad.com/italmud/). It had some major issues with download management and audio playback, but a recent update reduced these to minor issues, at least for me.

Comment: is it worth the $25?

Comment: @SethJ all things considered I think that's a fair price, but of course it feels very expensive in the scope of iOS apps. I think you would get a lot more mileage out of it if you have an iPad for it too. It's a little cramped on the iPhone.